# Iterating Over Numpy Array for NLP Application

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, word2vec

I have a Word2Vec model that I'm building where I have a vocab_list of about 30k words.  I have a list of sentences (sentence_list) about 150k large.  I am trying to remove tokens (words) from the sentences that weren't included in vocab_list.  The task seemed simple, but nesting for loops and reallocating memory is slow using the below code.  This task took approx. 1hr to run so I don't want to repeat it.

Is there a cleaner way to try this?

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

start=datetime.now()
timing=[]
result=[]
counter=0
for sent in sentences_list:
    counter+=1
    if counter %1000==0 or counter==1:
        print(counter, 'row of', len(sentences_list), ' Elapsed time: ', datetime.now()-start)
        timing.append([counter, datetime.now()-start])
    final_tokens=[]
    for token in sent:
        if token in vocab_list:
            final_tokens.append(token)
    #if len(final_tokens)>0:
    result.append(final_tokens)
print(counter, 'row of', len(sentences_list),' Elapsed time: ', datetime.now()-start)
timing.append([counter, datetime.now()-start])
sentences=result
del result
timing=pd.DataFrame(timing, columns=['Counter', 'Elapsed_Time'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that typical word2vec implementations (like Google's original `word2vec.c` or `gensim` `Word2Vec`) will often just ignore words in their input that aren't part of their established vocabulary (as specified by `vocab_list` or enforced via a `min_count`). So you may not need to perform this filtering at all.

Using a more-idiomatic Python list-comprehension *might* be noticeably faster (and would certainly be more compact). Your code could simply be:

```
filtered_sentences = [ 
    [word for word in sent if word in vocab_list] 
    for sent in sentences_list
]
```

Comment: Does appear to be about 6% faster.  I will look into gensim library to see if words not in vocab can be easily eliminated from sentences_list.

Comment: I'm surprised it's only 6% faster. Is `sentences_list` a simple list-of-list-of-string-tokens, or something else that's doing IO access or preprocessing of text files before yielding individual items? Also, how large is the average/extreme individual `sentence`? And again, if your ultimate aim is word2vec-training, you don't have to remove those words yourself - the training will ignore them quite efficiently at little up-front cost. Why do you want them removed?

Comment: I only ran a scaled test, but I'll rerun it on a the entire dataset tomorrow.  Thanks again for everything.